# Crashes to mainActivity screen

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

i did a login from my created database, when i try to login the screen should go to HomeActivity but it looks like it crashes back to the mainActivity tryed to change the location still crashes, myabie anyone has any ideas?

Code from Login class

```
    package com.example.laivumusis;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username, password;
    Button login, register;
    DatabaseLogin databaseLogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        databaseLogin = new DatabaseLogin(this);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usernameValue = username.getText().toString(); //???????
                String passwordValue = password.getText().toString();

                if(databaseLogin.isLoginValid(usernameValue, passwordValue)){ //should go to Home activity but crashes to main
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   //Pop up
                }
                    else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       //goes to register tab
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }
}
```

error from debug:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.laivumusis.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:34)
```

Added question marks to the row where the problem is shown

Adding xml code myabie youl see the problem :(

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <TextView
        android:text="Login form"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#971919"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <EditText
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Changes the R.id not it drops another problem from the debugger

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "''": syntax error in "Select count (*) from user where username=' 'and password''"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.laivumusis, PID: 21418
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "''": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: Select count (*) from user where username=' 'and password''
```

Database code:

```
    package com.example.laivumusis;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseLogin extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        static String name = "database";
        static int version = 1;

        String createTableUser = "CREATE TABLE if not exists \"User\" (\n" +    //per DB Browseri sukurem lentele
                "\t\"ID\"\tINTEGER,\n" +
                "\t\"Username\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Password\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Email\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Country\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Dob\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Gender\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\tPRIMARY KEY(\"ID\" AUTOINCREMENT)\n" +
                ")";

    public DatabaseLogin(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, name, null, version);

        getWritableDatabase().execSQL(createTableUser);

    }

    public void  insertUser(ContentValues contentValues){

        getWritableDatabase().insert("user", "", contentValues);

    }

    public boolean isLoginValid(String username, String password){

        String sql= "Select count (*) from user where username=' " +username+ "'and password'" +password+"'";
        SQLiteStatement statment = getReadableDatabase().compileStatement(sql);
        long l = statment.simpleQueryForLong();
        statment.close();

        if (l==1) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should share stack trace. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the "Login Successful" toast being displayed?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: In DatabaseLogin you need to check your database is work or not .it crash because your database not work. Debug app .

Comment: Database works it saves everything, the message doesn't pop up but everything but that works great

Comment: Make sure you are using the same id's for editText in the layout...

Comment: The id's are the same, checked the layout everything look like it should be

Comment: @LukasKaščiukevičius I have post a answer that might helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is you have add wrong reference. R.id.username need to change to R.id.Username in here [findViewById(R.id.username)]

Comment: Thx didin't even saw that, but i have so other problem :(

Comment: If this is your first question answer accept & put second issue you have

Comment: I edited the post if you have time you can peak at it :)

Comment: you have to put DatabaseLogin class. & most probably there is no equal sign in sql. This might be the case to verify put the above class code.

Comment: yea sry addit now

Comment: put equal sign in this code near password. and put space in " and password" . String sql= "Select count (*) from user where username=' " +username+ "' and password ='" +password+"'";

Comment: Yea thx for the help dude, and sry for the late response it worked perfectly :)